# Terraria truffle

Tags: terraria-mobile

In terraria I have 2 above ground mushroom bio,e 2 block thick and suitable homes. It says he would like to settle but he won't come. Plz help. Ps I have defeated plantera

Answer (score 0):

It says that you need 100 or more mushroom blocks and build a suitable house for him, that's all I know